# Showing SSRS reports page with in the browser using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services

I'm just trying to display the SSRS report page with in the ASP.NET MVC View. Nothing fancy. Not trying to use the webforms' reportviewer control or anything. I've tried using `<iframe>` in the view. But, It doesn't occupy the entire body of the page, and also throws the below JScript error if I try to click on any of the folders on SSRS.

[image]

" Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'className': object is null or undefined "

Below is my view and the controller.

**Layout.cshtml**`<li>@Html.ActionLink("View Reports","ViewReports","Home")</li>`

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult ViewReports()
        {
            return View("reports");
        }
```

**Reports.cshtml**`<iframe src ="https://test-server/Reports"></iframe>`
Below is how i see the SSRS on my MVC Site. Is there any other of getting this working ? something like a browser control that occupies all of the body content in the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(I can't see your image due tue proxy issues.)
Use redirection:

```
public ActionResult ViewReports()
{
    return Redirect("https://test-server/Reports");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually used Redirect before, and it worked perfectly well. But, I'd like to make the reports look like it is running inside my app. since I've got master page layouts, nav bars and stuff, I don't them to disappear when the user clicks on the reports link. any suggestions please ?

Comment: below is the error I get when I run the app using '<iframe>' " Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'className': object is null or undefined "